# Listview with Dynamic Data

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I got a model that should populate the listview. Depending on the type I need to show the list of possible answers.

```
{
    "Question" (string): ("Please choose the one of the followings best suitable to your situation.")
    Type (enum) (Type.Radio, Type.FreeText, Type.Number, Type.Checkbox)
    List<Answers> ({"It was cold inside.", 
        "It was cold but the heaters turned on after asking." 
        "It was warm" })
    RequiresComments (bool) (true)
}
```

The amount of questions will come from server. It might be 70 question and some of them as radio, some of them as checkbox, some of them just free text.

I did this on Android and iOS but I have no idea how to do is on Windows Phone 8.1. Can anyone show me an example or point me into right direction?

Comment: Here is what I think after checking the possibiltiies:
QuestionListView's data template will have AnswerListView inside.
AnswerListView's template type will be binded to Type enum.
So when I give list of answers, it will use the correct template to populate it.

Answer (score 0):

In your view have a radio buttons with vales from enum. Once the user selects the type fetch the answers from server.

After fetching the list of answers. Set the listview's(in your view) Itemssource to the list of answers that you obtained.

The comment part,you can use the bool and change the visibility of the comment textbox(in your view) using a converter.